# AngularJs : Set conditional min and max value for validation in number input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a web page which contains a form with two number input fields `field1` and `field2`. I'm doing the validation on these fields. `field1` has a `min` value 1 and `max` value 100000 but `field2` should have `min` value is `max` of `field1` or 1, anything which is greater and `max` is 100000. I tried to assign the `ng-model` of `field1` as `min` of `field2` but it not working.

```
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <input ng-model="priceminrange" name="priceminrange" type="number"
    class="form-control" value="" placeholder="MinRange" min="1" max="100000">
    <span ng-show="form.priceminrange.$error.number">The value is not a valid number</span> 
    <span ng-show="form.priceminrange.$error.min || form.priceminrange.$error.max">
    The value must be in range 1 to 100000</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input ng-model="pricemaxrange" name="pricemaxrange" type="number"
    class="form-control" value="" placeholder="MaxRange" min={{priceminrange}} max="100000">
    <span ng-show="form.pricemaxrange.$error.number">The value is not a valid number</span> 
    <span ng-show="form.pricemaxrange.$error.min || form.pricemaxrange.$error.max">
    The value must be in range {{priceminrange}} to 100000</span>
    form.pricemaxrange.$error = {{form.pricemaxrange.$error}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

On controller create scope.

```
$scope.priceminrange = 1;
```

Answer (score 8):

You were close. The object `priceminrange` is an Angular object that contains several methods and properties, all relating to the model. The property you want is called `$modelValue`, which contains the value entered by the user after it is parsed to its correct data type (number in this case).

Something like this should work, assuming you have wrapped the input elements in a form named "form."

```
<input ng-model="pricemaxrange" type="number" min="{{form.priceminrange.$modelValue}}">
```